# mySQL Statement for group by with count over 1

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

Is there a faster version of the following SQL statement?

```
SELECT Name, Anzahl
FROM (

SELECT Name, count( * ) AS Anzahl
FROM `Product`
GROUP BY Name
)m
WHERE Anzahl >1
```

Comment: `SELECT Name, count( * ) AS Anzahl
FROM Product
GROUP BY Name having Anzahl > 1 ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need another select the following should do what you need

```
SELECT Name, 
count( * ) AS Anzahl 
FROM Product 
GROUP BY Name 
having Anzahl > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need 2 selcts, try this:

```
SELECT Name, count( * ) AS Anzahl
FROM `Product`
GROUP BY Name
HAVING Anzahl >1
```

what you did with 2 selcts was   select  EVERYTHING FROM (SELECT EVERYTHING) WHERE COUNT > 1 so why not make it SELECT EVERYTHING WHERE COUNT > 1 ;)

Hope this answers your question